# CircleAvatar flutter not fit the image inside the circle

Tags: user-interface, flutter, mobile, dart

please help, i need to put an image inside `circleAvatar` widget, but the image doesn't show perfectly.

this issue, only shown on android devices

[image]

```
                     return Center(
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 100.0,
                          backgroundImage: ExactAssetImage(
                            'assets/images/ic_Photo-L.png',
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
```

Comment: `"but the image doesn't show prefectly"` - what you mean by that?

Comment: sorry, this is the link for what i mean. https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2DNJ.png

Comment: `Center(
          child: CircleAvatar(radius: 100.0, backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/ico-binoculars.svg?v=d4dbaac4eec9')),
        ),`

Comment: i'm sorry. not working

Comment: the result stil same with this https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2DNJ.png

Comment: https://pastebin.com/BuzYYMSn run it in https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ - what do you see?

Comment: when used my code in the dartpad.dartlang.org, its work fine too ? it seems my dart sdk version causing the problem ?

Comment: did my code work? did you run it on both: https://dartpad.dartlang.org and your SDK?

Comment: both code working fine in dartpad, but not in my genymotion devices/ android devices. but working fine in ios devices

Comment: what `flutter --version`?

Comment: Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable •

Comment: `"channel stable"` strange..., maybe check https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues if there is anything related to this

Comment: Is CircleAvatar compulsory? you can do it using other widget too.

Comment: i alredy make a bug report regarding this issue. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/48870

Answer (score 4):

Try using **ClipOval with Container**  if ***CircleAvatar*** is not compulsory.

```
 return Center(
      child: ClipOval(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          color: Colors.grey.shade200,
          child: Image.asset(
            'assets/images/ic_Photo-L.png',
            width: 200.0,
            height: 200.0,
            fit: BoxFit.contain,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
```